# When to choose IP Whitelisting over VNet peering?

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-virtual-network, vpc-peering

To connect two VNets or more together, VNet peering can be used. However, I noticed that in my organization, some are using NSGs to whitelist IP addresses between VNets. Is there an advantage or best practices regarding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelisting IPs is usually not recommended when you can avoid doing so, following Zero Trust pattern.

Depending on your constraints and organization rules, you might want to leverage [VNet Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) with a [Hub-and-Spoke topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/security/design-network-segmentation#pattern-3-multiple-vnets-in-a-hub-and-spoke-model) (or not) or even [Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview) across VNets/regions for PaaS (or VMs behind a Load Balancer) to make sure traffic is flowing via the Microsoft backbone and not via the Internet, IP spoofing being a common attack.

I would always refer to the [Microsoft Well-Architected Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/security/design-network-connectivity) for such questions.